# How does this object have access to a method of another object defined in an external file?

Tags: javascript

```
var DragDrop = function(){
        var dragdrop = new EventTarget(),
        dragging = null,
        diffX = 0,
        diffY = 0;

// some code here

}();

 DragDrop.addHandler("dragstart", function(event){
        var status = document.getElementById("status");
        status.innerHTML = "Started dragging " + event.target.id;
    });
```

The constructor of EventTarget is defined in an external file called EventTarget.js. Method "addHandler" is a method of EventTarget.prototype which is assigned to an object literal. My question is, how does DragDrop gain access to the EventTarget.prototype's method when the method is defined in another object in an external file? edit: Is there some sort of inheritance taking place here?

Comment: No matter in which file object is defined. Only in which `scope`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All scripts loaded by the browser are injected into the same execution environment.

The only issues caused by having multiple files are timing related. Code in one file can't access objects created by another file until that other file has been loaded.

Scope is determined only at function level.